# Why must a method be declared in a C++ class definition?

Tags: c++, declaration

If only define this method it will have a compiler error.

```
void classA::testMethod() {    
}
```

And so it must be declared first:

```
class classA {    
   void testMethod();
};
```

Why should these be declared?

I know for common C method methods it is not needed declare, but they can just be defined:

```
void test() {
}
```

Comment: you can declare functions outside of a class as in c also

Comment: @jonynz: That doesn't make sense, C doesn't have classes or methods.

Comment: Because this is how C++ was defined. However, on a more practical point, this would make code potentially much *harder* to correctly write. This is especially true because in C++, excluding templates, the class definition often appears separately from the class implementation - if these ad-hoc definitions were allowed then a consumer of the type would need access to the relevant implementation (to be able to have access to the full definition).

Comment: @user2864740: I'm not sure about that statement. Namespaces do not have this rule.

Comment: Short of "the standard say so", it is C++'s way of associating member methods with a class/struct (as opposed to non-member and friend methods, and other free functions).

Comment: @MSalters That's fine (or rather, is not subject to the same complications). As in most statically-typed languages, Namespaces are "open" as they [mostly] represent logical groupings for types - but only the known types (or functions in C++) declared in such can be used.

Comment: @jaifu: I think it would help if you clarified whether you want an explanation of ***why*** the C++ Standard would/might insist on this, or confirmation that the C++ Standard ***does*** insist on this (e.g. a corresponding quote from the Standard).

Comment: @user2864740 that's not a particularly compelling reason - the same concerns are equally relevant for functions that are global or in namespaces, which may equally form an API in a header and there the same consequences to any choice of inline vs. out-of-line, but namespaces are not forced to be contiguous in lines of source code the way classes/structs are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several secondary reasons both objective and subjective (i.e. allows to specify visibility, serves as an interface for the class and probably several others related to compiling and linking phases and TU symbols visibility, not to mention a class is the basic encapsulation unit, with all that implies) but an unquestionable one is that **the standard dictates it**:

N3797 - class.mfct/p2

> **A member function may be defined (8.4) in its class definition, in
>   which case it is an inline member function (7.1.2), or it may be
>   defined outside of its class definition if it has already been
>   declared but not defined in its class definition.** A member function
>   definition that appears outside of the class definition shall appear
>   in a namespace scope enclosing the class definition. Except for member
>   function definitions that appear outside of a class definition, and
>   except for explicit specializations of member functions of class
>   templates and member function templates (14.7) appearing outside of
>   the class definition, a member function shall not be redeclared.

emphasis mine.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to declare the method before you define it, but you need to declare class methods in the class. Else it wouldn't be a class method.

That may seem like a contradiction, but a definition is also a declaration. So what this means is that the definition may appear in the class itself:

```
class A {
  void testMethod() { /*...*/ } 
};
```

[edit]
Also, practically speaking, inside the class declaration there are `private`, `protected` and `public` parts. This is needed to for encapsulation. If you could declare methods outside the class, you would lose encapsulation. Anybody could access private members merely by defining extra getters and setters, even when those would not make sense. Class invariants would become meaningless.

Comment: @TonyD You don't downvote other questions to have another answer rise up, that's your personal opinion and others might disagree. Now I understand who downvoted my answer too. You're meant to downvote if the answer is wrong/unuseful, not if you think there's a better one or your favorite one.

Comment: "If you could declare methods outside the class, you would lose encapsulation." Of course, you could get around this issue by allowing access modifiers on each method definition a la Java.

Answer (score 6):

It helps encapsulation. If you have a class A

```
class A {
public:
  foo();
  bar();
}
```

You can be sure that only methods `foo` and `bar` mess with the private data members of the class. (Or pointer magic or undefined behavior of course)

Comment: I don't see how this relates.

Comment: @user2864740 It would be possible to define the free-standing `void classA::testMethod(){ ... }` form to mean that you want to extend the class. But that's not the case in C++.

Comment: What does encapsulation have to do with any of this? C++ *could* have been defined to do some silly magic such as promoting such found definitions into class definitions (which makes little sense, especially given that definitions are often separate from the implementation). But none of this relates to encapsulation.

Comment: @user2864740 C++ *could* have been defined with some silly magic (introduced in the OPs question - at least that's how I understood the question) I tried to point out a reason *why* it is not defined that way.

Comment: My argument is that it is not related to encapsulation. There are many practical (from code management and compiling) reasons as to why C++ (and almost every other statically-typed language) requires a declaration up-front; in the case of Java and C# the definition also serves as the declaration, but is still wrapped in a class definition.

Comment: @user2864740 OK, you give your class a `private` data member, and then I externally add `YourClass::myFunction()` which gets "promoted" to member and as such, suddenly has access to private names. So it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: +1 this squarely addresses my understanding of the question too... classes are different from e.g. namespaces in forcing a grouping of class members/friend etc. in code, and a primary reason is better encapsulation... otherwise anywhere else in the translation unit, perhaps in a .cpp after seeing the class in a header, you could add arbitrary "member" functionality, and you'd never know when you'd seen the full class API.  @user2864740: some of those languages don't mandate this - e.g. C# allows disjoint "partial" class definitions - yikes.

Comment: @user2864740: *"...many practical (from code management and compiling) reasons as to why C++ ... requires a declaration up-front"* - for data members and virtual functions yes, not really for member functions that haven't yet been called from anywhere in the translation unit.  As above - encapsulation is a more compelling reason.

Answer (score 3):

All of the previous answers are correct as far as they go, but
they fail to point out the reason behind the rule.  In C++,
a class definition is closed; you cannot add to it later.  This
is necessary for non-static data members, since they determine
the size (and the implicitly generated special functions), but
it is a basic principle in C++ for all class members: not just
data, but functions, types, etc.  It is considered essential for
good encapsulation.

This is true for most (but not all) languages which support the
concept of class.

This also explains why it the situation is different for
namespaces (which aren't closed).

Comment: +1 (earlier) but in fairness "All of the previous answers" except Csq's.

Answer (score 2):

"Methods" or "member functions" (as is the more common terminology in C++) are part of the class declaration. Since you must declare a C++ class in one single place, you must make sure that all "member functions" (or "methods") are already present in that declaration.

> I know for common C method methods it is not needed declare, but they
>   can just be defined

When you refer a "common C method" in C++, you actually mean a "common function". Note that you can declare classes anywhere you can declare such functions.

Also, note that you can declare a member function with a body. You do not have to separate declaration and definition. I.e. this is perfectly valid:

```
class A{
   void privateMethod() {
       // do something here...
   }
public:
   void publicMethod() {
       // do something here...
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Note the use of the qualifier `::`. It means

- on the left you have a namespace or class identifier
- on the right you have a namespace, class, or method / function identifier

So writing `void A::testMethod()` assumes that there is a class or namespace `A` defined - this is how C++ is defined. And this applies to

```
void A::testMethod();
```

as well as to

```
void A::testMethod()
{
}
```

Also note the global namespace where you have indeed nothing at the left of `::` as in

```
void ::testMethod()
{
}
```

And by definition the global namespace is always defined so the above code defines a function similar to C-style without the qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it were not mandated by the standard, there are the following two reasons why you need to declare all class methods in the class definition.

1. You can only declare something as public, private or protected in the class declaration, you can't do so at the method definition in the .cpp file.  So what visibility would your free-standing class method have?
2. If the standard decided to select one of the three as the default (C++ defaults to private), and place that visibility on your method, you now have a scoping problem.  Even the most restrictive visibility (private) means that you can use the method in any other member method, *including those defined before it in the source file*.  Without the declaration in the class definition, those earlier functions would not be aware of your free standing method, thus you violate the scoping rules.

In your foo.h header:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo() {}
    virtual ~foo() {}

    declaredMethod();
};
```

In your foo.cpp

```
foo::declaredMethod()
{
    ...
    freeStandingMethod();   // This should be legal, but it can't work since we
                            //  haven't seen foo::freeStandingMethod() yet
    ...
}

foo::freeStandingMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

Even if you could make this work in the same .cpp file, it's legal to place `foo::freeStandingMethod()` in a different .cpp file from `foo::declaredMethod()` at which point this becomes impossible.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but you might find it informative and fun.
Adding 2 template functions to your class will effectively allow you to call any free function that takes an object of that class as the first parameter:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct puppy {
   puppy(std::string name)
   : _name(std::move(name))
   {}

   const std::string& name() const noexcept {
      return _name;
   }

  void set_name(std::string name) {
    _name = std::move(name);
  }

    template<class F, class ...Args>
      auto perform(F&& f, Args&&...args) const 
      -> decltype(f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
      return f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<class F, class ...Args>
      auto perform(F&& f, Args&&...args) 
      -> decltype(f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
      return f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
   std::string _name;
};


void woof(const puppy& p) {
   std::cout << "puppy " << p.name() << " woofs!" << std::endl;   
}

void indented_woof(const puppy&p, size_t indent) {
    std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ');
    woof(p);
}

void complex_woof(const puppy& p, int woofs)
{
    std::cout << "attention!" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0  ; i < woofs ; ++i) {
    p.perform(indented_woof, 4);
  }
}

std::string name_change(puppy& p, std::string(new_name))
{
  auto old_name = p.name();
  p.set_name(std::move(new_name));
  return old_name;
}

int main()
{
  puppy fido { "fido" };

  fido.perform(woof);
  fido.perform(complex_woof, 10);
  auto old_name = fido.perform(name_change, "bonzo");
  fido.perform(woof);
  std::cout << "changed name from " << old_name << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In answer to the (now deleted) comment:
One version of perform has to be const to support functions that take a non-const puppy&.

Answer (score 1):

`why should declare these? I know for common c method, there is no need to declare, instead of it just define it:`

There is no method in C, just attribute of an struct, wich can be function Pointeur, then associated to a function addresse.

Furthermore you have to declare it in the class definition for the same reason you do it in C:

The compilateur will transform this pre-declaration into a function pointeur then associate to the said methode int the construction of your object.

If a definition of a C++ class should be transformed to a C struct the code would be like this:

```
struct Aclass {
 void (*Amethode))(int);
}
void Amethode(int) { return (0); }
Aclass primaryObject = {&Amethode};
Aclass* AclassConstructor() {
 Aclass* object;
 object = malloc(sizeof(Aclass));
 memcpy(object, primaryObject, sizeof(Aclass));
 return (object);
}
```

Comment: Are you claiming that member funcions in C++ are implemented in terms of function pointer attributes? This is not actually the case. Member functions are statically defined and statically resolved by the compiler. Function pointers enter into it when using virtual functions, but in a different way than what I think you are describing.

Comment: @Magnus Hoff In facts you're right it's not the case but it's more easy to understand for a debuting programmer, or i think  so...

Comment: While the scheme you are describing would work, it does not represent what is actually happening and is thus confusing. I think the following is much easier to understand, in addition to being a much closer representation of what's actually going on: http://ideone.com/4xhr8T

Comment: You're right... i should have presented it like this!

Comment: No thanks i'm more used in my way of C object oriented code:)

Comment: This is very confusing.  The question is about C++, not C, and in C++, classes can have member functions (which is one of the common meanings of method), and not just pointers to functions.  And your image of a C struct as the implementation of a class is totally incorrect; the original C++ compiler (CFront) did generate C, but the generated C looked nothing like what you have posted.